# How to know the key which has been pressed by users?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a console application in C.

I am trying to detect which key has been pressed by users:

```
if (...)
    printf ("Shift + Right Arrow");
if (...)
    printf ("Right Arrow");
if (...)
    printf ("中"); // (Big5(CP950): 0xA4 0xA4)
if (...)
    printf ("文"); // (Big5(CP950): 0xA4 0xE5)
....
```

How do I detect which has been pressed by users?

Comment: Is it MFC or you are using win32 api or console?

Comment: @Digital_Reality A console app in C :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winuser.h>

BOOL isPressShift(){
    return (SHORT)0x8000 & GetKeyState( VK_SHIFT );
}

BOOL isPressRightArrow(){
    return (SHORT)0x8000 & GetKeyState( VK_RIGHT );
}


int main(void){
//  ... do something
    if(isPressShift() && isPressRightArrow())
        printf("Shift + Right Arrow\n");
    if(isPressRightArrow())
        printf("Right Arrow\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the virtual keys [heres a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: which function should I use?

Comment: Do you have a message loop or are you writing a console app?

Comment: [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx)